# Can not use the data from a node Server in angular

Tags: node.js, api, angular7

i tried making my own weather forecast. I took darksky for the data.
My server is a short node.js server with a geodata and a forecast part.

Forecast part:
...

```
const request = require('request');

const forecast = (latitude, longitude, callback) => {
  const url =
   darksky url
  var weatherData = {};

  request({ url, json: true }, (error, { body }) => {
    if (error) {
      callback('Unable to connect to weather service', undefined);
    } else if (body.error) {
      callback('Unable to find location', undefined);
    } else {
      callback(
        undefined,
        (weatherData = {
          daily: body.daily.data[0].summary,
          temp: body.currently.temperature,
          regen: body.currently.precipProbability
        })
      );
    }
  });
};

module.exports = forecast;
```

...

the server:

...

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const geocode = require('./utils/geocode');
const forecast = require('./utils/forecast');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.search);
  geocode(req.query.search, (error, { latitude, longitude, location } = {}) => {
    if (error) {
        return res.send({ error });
    }

    forecast(latitude, longitude, (error, forecastData) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.send({ error });
        }
        const data =({
            location,
            forecast: forecastData
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is up and running");
});
```

...

Now i am trying to get this in my angular 7 app.

I made a service:

...

```
 getDataServer(addy: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + addy).subscribe(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData);
    });
  }
```

...

Responsedata has all the required information in this format:

{location: Stuttgart, forcast: { daily: 'sun', regen: 0, temp: 17}}

Now i tried getting the forecast in my component, but this will not work. I tried making an Observable and subscribe but nothing worked.

Maybe you have a little hint,

thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Please Modify your service Code as

```
getDataServer(addy: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + addy).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

And call this Service in your component as

```
this.your_service_property.getDataServer(addy).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
// Try updating your html here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it was a hugh help for me. I tried this in almost the same way but with your help i got the solution for the service, had to change it to:

```
getDataServer(addy: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + addy).pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

got an error from res.json(). HttpClient changed and i got an json object back.

Next thing in the component:

```
this.your_service_property.getDataServer(addy).subscribe((data: any) => {
console.log(data);
```

Had to use any for the data property. Without i always got an error like

Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Object', if i tried to get some value from data - data.location. Tried it with an interface but still an error, so i took the easiest way with any and it worked.

But the part with the interface is still in my mind and i will try this later.